# Warning message in setwd - R

Tags: r, setwd

I have a workflow with three different operating systems and I use the `switch` function in `R` to change my working directory between them.

It works fine in Windows and macOS, but in Linux, returns a warning message and I don't know why.

I'm using Elementary OS 5.1 Hera, and that's the code:

```
switch (Sys.info()["sysname"],
        Linux = setwd("~/Documentos/GitHub/Economic Activity Monitor"),
        Darwin = setwd("~/Documents/GitHub/Economic Activity Monitor"),
        Windows = setwd("~/GitHub/Economic Activity Monitor")
)
```

The warning message:

```
#Warning message:
#In normalizePath(dirname(f)) :
#  path[1]="NA": No such file or directory
```

It changes the working directory, but I would like to understand why is returning that message only on Linux.

Comment: What does `dirname(f)` with `f <- "~/Documentos/etc"` return?

Comment: Returns ```"/home/alexandre/Documentos"```.

Comment: The rest of the path (`"GitHub/Monitor de Atividade Econômica"`) is missing?

Comment: I'm sorry, I got it wrong, it returns ```"/home/alexandre/Documentos/GitHub/Monitor de Atividade Econômica"```.

Comment: Encoding issues? I usually encounter these if I use the same script on Windows and Mac.

Comment: The rest of the code works perfectly on the 3 systems, I just don't understand this warning message.

Comment: I don't understand it either because it's not in a language I speak. You should do `Sys.setenv("LANGUAGE"="EN")` (and preferably add that to your Rprofile.site files).

Comment: I'm sorry, I already fixed the question.

Comment: You should not have changed the directory name. The letter `ô` could be the reason for encoding issues. (In my language, the culprits are usually `ä`, `ö`, `ü`, `ß`.)

Comment: Even changing the folder names and redoing the test, it returns the same warning message.